# Do SendGrid automatically convert HTML messages to plain text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I'm sending a confirmation email to users who register and want to be sure that there is both an HTML and plain text version in case a user's email client doesn't display HTML, but I'm a little confused about how to do this. Here is some of my code:

```
private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "hello@example.com", "Example");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }



private async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID, string subject)
    {
        string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
           new { userId = userID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject, "<p>Example confirmation message</p>");


        return callbackUrl;
    }
```

The code I have works and sends an HTML email, but what happens for users who have email clients that don't display HTML? Does `myMessage.Text = message.Body;` automatically take `"<p>Example confirmation message</p>"` and convert it to plain text? If not, how do I add in a message that get's used for the text version?

EDIT: The HTML I will be using will generally be formatted similar to this:

```
<p style="color:#333;">First paragraph</p>
<p style="color:#333;">Second paragraph <a href="https://www.somelink.com">Click here</a></p>
<p style="color:#333;"> Third <br> paragraph</p>
```

Comment: No it doesn't automatically convert it. You are supposed to provide plain text.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the HtmlAgilityPack (NuGet) to do the conversion from html to plain text:

```
HtmlToText htt = new HtmlToText();
string plaintText = htt.ConvertHtml(htmlString);
```

And you would need this HtmlCovert.cs:

```
#region

using System.IO;

#endregion

namespace NameSapceBlah
{
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    public class HtmlToText
{
    #region Public Methods

    public string Convert(string path)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        this.ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, sw);
        sw.Flush();
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public string ConvertHtml(string html)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        this.ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, sw);
        sw.Flush();
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public void ConvertTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
    {
        string html;
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case HtmlNodeType.Comment:
                // don't output comments
                break;

            case HtmlNodeType.Document:
                this.ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
                break;

            case HtmlNodeType.Text:
                // script and style must not be output
                string parentName = node.ParentNode.Name;
                if ((parentName == "script") || (parentName == "style"))
                    break;

                // get text
                html = ((HtmlTextNode)node).Text;

                // is it in fact a special closing node output as text?
                if (HtmlNode.IsOverlappedClosingElement(html))
                    break;

                // check the text is meaningful and not a bunch of whitespaces
                if (html.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    outText.Write(HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(html));
                }
                break;

            case HtmlNodeType.Element:
                switch (node.Name)
                {
                    case "p":
                        // treat paragraphs as crlf
                        outText.Write("\r\n");
                        break;
                }

                if (node.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    this.ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void ConvertContentTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode subnode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            this.ConvertTo(subnode, outText);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Then your method should work:
myMessage.Text = plainText;

event though I'd create an alternative HTML view and send the plainText as the email subject.

```
 ContentType mimeType = new ContentType("text/html");
 AlternateView alternate =   AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlString, mimeType);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide **text** alternative yourself. You could convert html to text by replacing **br** tags to newline and remove other html formatting. For example:

```
// convert br's to newline
var textString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(htmlString, "\\s*<\\s*[bB][rR]\\s*/\\s*>\\s*", Environment.NewLine);

// remove html tags
textString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(textString, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This looks like a good path, but the only problems are that my HTML is now completely on one line and the link I was using is gone. It would be ideal if the link would go from: <a href="www.examplelink.com">click here</a> to: www.examplelink.com

Comment: I edited my original post and added a better example of what type of HTML I will be using

Comment: You can extract href attribute from link with another regex: `<a.+?\s*href\s*=\s*["\']?([^"\'\s>]+)["\']?` See https://regex101.com/r/oH3yT4/1